# There is an entry for table "stores", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to select latest 4 deals from my stores, with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, and Im getting this error:

> There is an entry for table "stores", but it cannot be referenced from
>   this part of the query

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
end
```

My Query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT stores.id AS store_id,       deals.*,
      dense_rank() OVER (
        PARTITION BY deals.stores.id
        ORDER BY deals.created_at DESC
      ) AS deal_rank
 FROM "deals" 
 INNER JOIN "listings" 
 ON "listings"."deal_id" = "deals"."id" 
 INNER JOIN "images" 
 ON "images"."id" = "deals"."image_id" 
 INNER JOIN "deals_stores" 
 ON "deals_stores"."deal_id" = "deals"."id" 
 INNER JOIN "stores" 
 ON "stores"."id" = "deals_stores"."store_id"  
 ORDER BY deals.created_at desc) 
 AS ranked_deals  
 WHERE (deal_rank <= 4)
```

Comment: Could you also post your table definitions? And is this part correct: deals.stores.id

Answer (score 0):

When defining a habtm relationship, you should prefer the plural version.

You need to change

`has_and_belongs_to_many :store`

to

`has_and_belongs_to_many :stores`